# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{n}}$$

I have no idea how to even start computing this series. I do know, however, that this series definitely converges. Solving it numerically results in a solution close to 1.29.
But, how would one compute this series analytically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sum has no known closed form, but the following relation is true:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{-k} = \int_0^1x^{-x}dx.$$
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: Unless, I'm misreading it somehow, the cited source says the value is $\int_0^1x^{-x}dx.$